# skip the screenlock

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-manifest

```
protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();        

        // If the screen is off then the device has been locked
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();

        //screen locked 
        if (!isScreenOn) {

            boolean pressed = onKeyDown(26, null);

            //power button pressed
            if(pressed){
                //remove keyguard
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);                 
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

                //start intent
                Intent i = new Intent(this, VoiceRecognitionActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }


        }
    }
```

the above code does is when power button is pressed, the keyguard will be dismissed and the activity onpaused will be resumed.

However, the keyguard is not dimissed when i pressed the power button, and i have to unlock manually.

When i pressed the power button, the window of my activity flashed for a second and the keyguard window is shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent phone from turning screen off (and locking the phone in result) you should use `WakeLock`. You can use [`PowerManager.newWakeLock()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#newWakeLock%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) with `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` or even 
`FULL_WAKE_LOCK`.

Comment: hi inazaruk, thank you for your reply. however, i am not trying to prevent the phone from sleeping.

i want to do something like when i pressed the power button to wake up the phone, it will auto go into a voiceRecognition activity where it will record an voice command. if the voice command matches, it will unlock the phone.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet may help:

```
    final Window win = getWindow();
    win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    // Turn on the screen unless we are being launched from the AlarmAlert
    // subclass.
    final boolean screenOff = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(SCREEN_OFF, false);
    if (!screenOff) {
        try {
            // API 8+
            win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
        } catch (final Throwable whocares) {
            // API 7+
            win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi jon, i have tried with your code..however, when i press the power button, my activity window flashes for less than a second and the keyguard shown up..?

Comment: you can't. Service has no way of getting a `Window` instance.

Comment: what if i use disableKeyguard(); in a Service?